# Advanced generic type annotations

Tags: python, generics, annotations, wrapper, type-variables

I have a Wrapper class (<<T.**init**>> is the part I am struggling with):

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(**kwargs: <<T.__init__>>):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        ...

    def __call__() -> T:
        return self.__orig_class__.__args__[-1](**self.kwargs)
```

I am using it like this:

`wrapped_class = Wrapper[SomeClass](**SomeClass_arguments)`

SomeClass_arguments are arguments that the SomeClass takes to its **init** method

I want to make static type checking and hinting work for SomeClass_arguments.
I was able to check them dynamically using the inspect module. But I would much rather prefer a static solution. I don't have always control over SomeClass as it can be either my class or some third-party class.

I cannot discuss the true intention of this design. But I need to wrap (add some levels of functionality) an object and at the same time separate the object definition `wrapped_class = Wrapper[SomeClass](**SomeClass_arguments)` and initialization wrapped_class().

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
from typing import Callable, Generic, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, cls: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        self._cls = cls
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __call__(self) -> T:
        return self._cls(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

wrap = Wrapper(int, '123')  # OK
wrap = Wrapper(int, [])  # gives error: list not compatible with arguments of int
```

It uses a `Callable[P, T]` where P is a `ParamSpec` to specify the type. The `P` is inferred from the first argument and the arguments passed.

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution. This has a flaw though. When wrap instance is called, it does not know that it produces int. I would have to defined it like this (Wrapper[int](int, 1)) which is repeating the name of the class. But this is progress and an interesting feature. Thanks

Comment: No, you don't need to repeat `[int]`. The `int` parameter passed in is enough for the static checker to know the return type is `int`. The `[int]` is inferred by the type checker.

Comment: What version of python and IDE are you using? My pycharm will not show me any hints for any class I try to use.

Comment: Also if I can make it work like this
def __class_getitem__(cls, params: Callable[P, T]):
    return super().__class_getitem__(params)
That would allow me to keep my old syntax, but sadly I cannot make this to work properly

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code with Python 3.11.4. The code above works well and the type checker shows an error on the last line.

Comment: We might have misunderstood each other. The error at the last line is shown to me. But
wrap = Wrapper(int, '123')
this_is_int = wrap()
this_is_int.___
Is not giving me any hints for int instances like 'real', 'numerator', 'to_bytes'

Comment: Hmm that is very interesting. On VSCode it also works and shows me completion for `this_is_int`. Does the problem go away if you explicit say `Wrapper[int](int, '123')`?

Comment: Yes
Wrapper[int](int, '123') will create a wrapper object, that when called will create something that pycharm recognise as int and will give int-related hints.
I am using python 3.8 and I am importing ParamSpec from typing_extensions, I will try to update my python